# How to install HTTP extension on PGadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm attempting to add the [HTTP extension](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http) to my pgadmin gui however when I run `CREATE EXTENSION http` I get `ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/http.control": No such file or directory`

The installation section on the readme is not very clear to me

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box support for http in PostgreSQL; I installed the http extension following these instructions:
If you are in linux:
apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-16 (or your postgresql version)
apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
git clone https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http.git
cd pgsql-http/
make
make install

If you are in windows, go to http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/371-http-extension.html and follow instructions

Then in a postgresql console or in pgAdmin, execute: CREATE EXTENSION http;

This is the repository addres in github: https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http.git

Hope this helps!